# Laravel 5: How to use remote model?

Tags: php, api, model, laravel-5

I want to create a model for external API, that would allow me to run operations like get(), where() etc. An example:

```
$users = UserFromApi::get(); // Get all users from api
$activeUsers = UserFromApi::where('active', 1)->get();
```

I come to Laravel from CakePHP. In CakePHP it's done by providing custom datasource and connection for the model.

For Laravel 4 there's a nice library called Trucker  (https://github.com/indatus/trucker), but I've found absolutely no other reasonable tool for L5.

What is the correct approach to the problem of "mapping model to external api"?

Comment: Trucker now supports Laravel 5 https://github.com/Indatus/trucker/tree/laravel-5#config-laravel

Answer (score 2):

Trucker now supports Laravel 5

Follow these instructions to configure Laravel 5
https://github.com/Indatus/trucker/tree/laravel-5#config-laravel

1. Add `"indatus/trucker": "dev-laravel-5"` to composer.json and run `composer update`
2. Publish the config files `php artisan vendor:publish indatus/trucker`
3. Add Trucker to your providers by pasting `'Trucker\TruckerServiceProvider::class'`
    in config/app.php

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

In config/database.php define your remote connection.

```
'mysql_remote' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Then if you are using eloquent models

```
class UserFromApi extends Eloquent {

     protected $connection = 'mysql_remote';
}
```

OR using the query builder

```
DB::connection('mysql_remote')->table('users')->select('email','surname')->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using MySQL at all! The data should come directly from the api (which returns results as json), no database involved.  I tried to use this approach with connection, but I didn't know how to emulate "api-driver".

Comment: Oops sorry! How about the Guzzle Library?
http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Well yes, but that concerns rather the connection layer and could be achieved by simple file_get_contents($url) in my case. And my question is strictly Laravelish :- ) My problem could be trimmed down to: "How to paginate records from api in Laravel". I think I will ask such question, it's more intuitive.